# JHipster Cassandra Docker Build

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster

I am attempting to use Cassandra with the latest release of JHipster (3.0.0) in a microservices architecture.

Here are the steps I've followed so far:

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster
mkdir C:\users\jd\dev\sample && cd $_
mkdir sample-gateway && cd $_
yo jhipster... (Create a gateway application w/ Cassandra)
```

I've installed the latest beta release of the [docker toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox).  From the console, I can see the following:

```
c:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd

c:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

I am able to successfully start my default machine using:

```
C:\Users\jd>docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown

C:\Users\jd>docker-machine start default
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Waiting for an IP...
Machine "default" was started.
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Started machines may have new IP addresses. You may need to re-run the `docker-machine env` command.

C:\Users\jd>docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
default   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.10.3
```

When I run the build step for Cassandra I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>docker-compose -f src\main\docker\cassandra.yml build
Building curatorial-cassandra
←[31mERROR←[0m: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to install Docker:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/
```

**Any ideas why I might be receiving this error?**

Comment: So I was successfully able to build the instance and start it using: `docker-compose -f src\main\docker\cassandra.yml up`.  Now I cannot seem to get the `docker-compose ps` to list the id.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the solution...

It looks like I needed to run the output from `$ docker-machine env default`.

When I run the output `FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO %i`, I am able to see this in my console:

```
C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>docker-compose -f src\main\docker\cassandra.yml build
Building sample-cassandra
←[31mERROR←[0m: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to install Docker:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/

C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO %i
C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\jd\.docker\machine\machines\default
C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>REM Run this command to configure your shell:
C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>REM       FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env default') DO %i

C:\Users\jd\dev\sample\sample-gateway>docker-compose -f src\main\docker\cassandra.yml build
Building sample-cassandra
Step 1 : FROM cassandra:2.2.5
2.2.5: Pulling from library/cassandra

←[0Bd7827f33: Pulling fs layer
←[0B95caeb02: Pulling fs layer
←[0B03976053: Pulling fs layer
←[0B44d757b1: Pulling fs layer
←[0B8b59ac1b: Pulling fs layer
←[0Bbadb6c0c: Pulling fs layer
←[0B72404d3b: Pulling fs layer
←[0Bd13f7785: Pulling fs layer
←[0B4e7f1560: Pulling fs layer
←[3Bd13f7785: Downloading [========================>                          ] 61.61 MB/124.8 MB
```

I will hold off on marking this as the answer in the hopes that someone with a more complete understanding of the docker-compose process can provide an answer.

I will also try to investigate more...

Comment: This answer is correct. You can usually shorten it to `eval $(docker-machine env default)`.